# Put "grid" on camera in Swift 2 (using UIimagePickerController)

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, uiimageview, swift2

So I have followed one of the few tutorials on how to access the camera with the `UIimagePickerController` and that works fine. (It even implements face detection as well which was my next step!)

But now I would like to create something like Apple's "grid" view with my own personally made grid. I have how to make an `ImageView` but after that I have a few more questions:

1. Would I make a separate image view and somehow layer it over the `UIimagePickerController` Image View that starts the camera?
2. Could I just make one `UIImageview` that already has the lines and then accesses the camera? If so how would I do that?
3. My final goal would be to detect if something (like a face that the face detector has found) has crossed over into the grid or possibly just map where it is on the screen. Is this possible? How would I get an object's location on the camera screen?

Comment: thanks for the edit @NathanTuggy!